# How can I access my Samba Server from a single windows PC using different usernames?

Tags: samba

I already setup Samba on Ubuntu Server. It's working fine, but I would like to have it accessed by any user using their username and password, in any windows PC that a user would choose to use. Please help me how to do that. Is that possible? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @utkuerd. Your answer game me clues and made me create more questions in my mind that forces mo to look for more answers. For that I thank you. I finally got it all working thanks to this post [here](http://www.jadota.com/2013/01/installing-samba4-on-ubuntu-12-04/comment-page-1/#comment-14503), I am now able to use a username with password to any PCs with Micro$#it Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

Samba has a built in user authentication mechanism. You can give users permission to access your shares and use `smbpasswd` to set their passwords. You can also synchronize user's login password with Samba password. Samba Server Configuration tool can help you on this, as illustrated [here](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/).

When you set up password for users, they'll be automatically required to enter it to access your shares from any computer that can access your Samba server. If your point is accessing with the **same passwords** they use on clients then you either need to set same passwords on clients and server, or you need a centralized authentication mechanism based on LDAP, Kerberos, etc.